QGIS - raster layer located off the basemap / doesn't display
I'm importing this raster layer (PTHA_19_San_Francisco_Amplitude_00475.tif) into QGIS. If I first import the OSM basemap using Quick Map Services, then import the raster layer and click "Zoom to Layer", it zooms to the correct location but the layer isn't visible at all. (Screenshot)
However, if I first import the raster layer and then the OSM basemap, the layer shows, but a hemisphere off the map (if that's what you call it?) (Screenshot)
I've tried setting the layer to different CRS. The metadata/readme said to use EPSG:4326, which causes all of these problems. If I switch to a different one, like EPSG:8716 (NAD California zone 3), the raster layer will be visible, but it'll be in the ocean somewhere, which makes sense. But I just don't know why it's visible in the ocean on the incorrect map projection, and invisible on the correct map projection of 4326.

make sure the .tfw (https://doc.app.box.com/v/capthadatav1/file/1189976938640) is also downloaded and in the same folder and same file name as the .tif (tif/tfw) this the world file (georeference) for each image.

It is indeed

Yeah, that's a bit suss. What's happening is that your layer is ending up on the next "world". Longitude wraps, so your is in the next -180->180 degree section. But when you Zoom to Layer, it's zooming to where it should be in the OpenStreetMap section, rather than where it has been placed, two hemispheres over! I can replicate your issue, and I can't see why your layer shouldn't be in the same area as the OpenStreetMap layer. QGIS normally has the smarts to handle this. So possibly a QGIS bug?
